# Randomizing MP3 files in Actionscript 2

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, random, mp3, actionscript-2

```
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.Event;

 playsong();
//var songs:Array=new Array("part0.mp3","part1.mp3","part2.mp3","part3.mp3","part4.mp3","part5.mp3","part6.mp3","part7.mp3","part8.mp3","part9.mp3","part10.mp3","part11.mp3","part12.mp3","part13.mp3","part14.mp3","part15.mp3","part16.mp3","part17.mp3","part18.mp3","part19.mp3","part20.mp3","part21.mp3","part22.mp3","part23.mp3","part24.mp3","part25.mp3","part26.mp3","part27.mp3","part28.mp3","part29.mp3","part30.mp3","part31.mp3","part32.mp3","part33.mp3","part34.mp3","part35.mp3","part36.mp3","part37.mp3","part38.mp3","part39.mp3","part40.mp3","part41.mp3","part42.mp3","part43.mp3","part44.mp3","part45.mp3","part46.mp3","part47.mp3","part48.mp3","part49.mp3","part50.mp3","part51.mp3","part52.mp3","part53.mp3","part54.mp3","part55.mp3","part56.mp3","part57.mp3","part58.mp3","part59.mp3","part60.mp3","part61.mp3","part62.mp3","part63.mp3","part64.mp3","part65.mp3","part66.mp3","part67.mp3","part68.mp3","part69.mp3","part70.mp3","part71.mp3","part72.mp3","part73.mp3","part74.mp3","part75.mp3","part76.mp3","part77.mp3","part78.mp3","part79.mp3","part80.mp3","part81.mp3","part82.mp3","part83.mp3","part84.mp3","part85.mp3","part86.mp3","part87.mp3","part88.mp3","part89.mp3","part90.mp3","part91.mp3","part92.mp3","part93.mp3","part94.mp3","part95.mp3","part96.mp3","part97.mp3","part98.mp3","part99.mp3","part100.mp3","part101.mp3");
 var sound:Sound;
 var soundChannel:SoundChannel;
 var randnum:uint;
 function playsong()
 {
 randnum=Math.floor(Math.random()*127);
 sound=new Sound();
 var songs:String= "part" + randnum + ".mp3";  
 sound.load(new URLRequest("file:///D:/parts/"+songs));
 soundChannel=sound.play();
 soundChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE,playrandomsong);
 }
 function playrandomsong(e:Event)
 {
 playsong();
 }
```

This is an Actionscript 3 code I am using to random MP3s in an array from a local directory.  It works, but my issue is that the application I am using it for is older and does not support AS3 - only AS2 and older.  Does anyone know what the equivalent to this code would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS2 none of the imported packages exist, there's no, `Event`, `SoundChannel` or `URLRequest` class, and the [`Sound`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/2/00001513.html#467182) class interface is different.

Untested:

```
var sound:Sound;
var randnum:Number;

function playsong()
{
    randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 127);
    var songs:String = "part" + randnum + ".mp3";  

    sound = new Sound();
    sound.onSoundComplete = playrandomsong;
    sound.loadSound("file:///D:/parts/" + songs, true);
}

function playrandomsong()
{
    playsong();
}
```

Comment: I just gave it a shot, works fine for me (locally ofcourse). You'll need to share a little more information about your movie/script/environment if you need further assistance.

Comment: As long as it plays in regular Flash Player, it should be fine...which, at the moment, it isn't.  I'm using Flash CS6, set to ActionScript 2.0 and "Access Local Files Only".  It should work, so I don't know why it isn't.  At AS3 script, conversely, still works just fine - just not what I need.  

Here's the SWF I compiled with your code.  Can you see if it works for you?

http://www.mediafire.com/?hqpjb522b72xlz6

Comment: Looking at the decompiled code, you're missing an actual initial call to `playsong()`. I've overlooked that call in your code, so hadn't included it in my snippet. Loading your SWF and invoking `playsong()` works fine over here.